# Convert float into string SQL and concatenate

Tags: sql-server

Basically, this is what I'm trying to do to output it in my cursor.

`'10% Cumulative Debt' + SELECT(STR(@CUML_DEBT_P10))`

The output should look like this.

Cumulative Debt at 10% + the value @CULM_DEBT_P10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CAST or CONVERT:

```
SELECT '10% Cumulative Debt ' + CAST(@CUML_DEBT_P10 AS VARCHAR(20));
```

or

```
SELECT CONCAT('10% Cumulative Debt ', CAST(@CUML_DEBT_P10 AS VARCHAR(20)));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to look this up but couldn't find the answer on here!